# Downloading large files hangs system

Tags: 11.04, firefox, performance, downloads

When Im trying to download large files, i.e. 1gb or more under FireFox, first of all it starts with very big download speed and in few seconds in almost get up to max (~11 MBps). It is downloading very fast, but when downloaded size becomes near 700-800mb and more, my system almost completely hangs, so I can do nothing - I just have to wait until it finishes downloading.

Also when it hangs, I can't see the download progress - it looks like it completely hangs. Sometimes, however, if the file size is near 1gb, the system comes back from hang, finishing download, but sometimes I just cant wait before system comes back and have to kill FF from `top` (it takes me 2 minutes to do this, because of very slow system performance).

I use Firefox as primary browser.

If I use `wget` with direct link to file - everything is fine. Speed at max, no performance decrease.

So what can I do?

Comment: When the system almost hangs, is the hard disk very active? How much RAM do you have? Arrange to have a clock applet visible, preferably displaying seconds: does it update regularly, irregularly, not at all? What if you start a terminal and run the command `while true; do date; sleep 1; done` in it? Can you reproduce this with a blank Firefox profile?

Comment: 1) seconds update irregularly. 2) I have 3gb RAM. 3) After downloading finished, firefox become gray and don't respond for 15-30 seconds, and then become normal. Seconds update period, and FF gray screen depends on file size. Near 1gb - is fine, more - starting to hang.

Comment: You can try to lower firefox process priority and see if that will help with hangs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [DownThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/201/) extension for Firefox. You will get better speeds, better download management and possibly will solve your problem.

Comment: I don't see how this possibly could be relevant. This is a “download accelerator”, but we're talking about downloading a large file here, not many small files. I mean, it could solve Igor's issue if it turns out to be some weird bug in Firefox that DownThemAll manages not to trigger, but if so I'd want a citation for the bug or some explanation.

Comment: Extension helped me to solve this problem in this way. But still if I download via firefox downloader - problem exist.